# Swiftの配列の要素を五十音順に並べたい。

Tags: swift

["さとう","あおき"、"おおの"]というように名前の文字列が入っている配列を、
「"あおき"、"おおの"、"さとう"」というように五十音順に並び変えるにはどのような方法が
ありますか？

```
class person :NSObject{

    var name : NSString?

    init(nam:NSString) {

    name = nam
    }

}


var person1 = person(nam: "おおの")
var person2 = person(nam: "さとう")
var person3 = person(nam: "あおき")

println(person1.name)
println(person2.name)
println(person3.name)
```

このようなインスタンスが入った配列の場合も同様に可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

このように出来ます。

```
var strings = ["さとう", "あおき", "おおの", "かみきど", "すずき"]
sort(strings) { str1, str2 in str1 > str2 }

strings.sort { (lhs, rhs) in return lhs < rhs }
```

http://qiita.com/mst/items/b18e9531ac0cbdf2f3c3

編集

```
class person {

    var name : NSString

    init(nam:NSString) {

        name = nam
    }

}


var person1 = person(nam: "おおの")
var person2 = person(nam: "さとう")
var person3 = person(nam: "あおき")

var people: Array<person> = []


people += [person1]
people += [person2]
people += [person3]

var sortedPeople = people.sorted({ ($0.name as? String) < ($1.name as? String)  })


println(person1.name)
println(person2.name)
println(person3.name)

println(sortedPeople[0].name)
println(sortedPeople[1].name)
println(sortedPeople[2].name)
```

もし片仮名対応も出来たいのなら、こんなふうに出来ます。

```
extension String {
    func hiragana() -> String {
        var str = ""
        for c in unicodeScalars {
            if c.value >= 0x30A1 && c.value <= 0x30F6 {
                str.append(UnicodeScalar(c.value-96))
            } else {
                str.append(c)
            }
        }
        return str
    }
}
class person {

    var name : NSString

    init(nam:NSString) {

        name = nam
    }

}


var person1 = person(nam: "おおの")
var person2 = person(nam: "さとう")
var person3 = person(nam: "あおき")
var person4 = person(nam: "カミキド")

var people: Array<person> = []


people += [person1]
people += [person2]
people += [person3]
people += [person4]

var sortedPeople = people.sorted({ ($0.name as String).hiragana() < ($1.name as String).hiragana()  })


println(person1.name)  //おおの
println(person2.name)  //さとう
println(person3.name)  //あおき
println(person4.name)　//カミキド

println(sortedPeople[0].name)  //あおき
println(sortedPeople[1].name)  //おおの
println(sortedPeople[2].name)  //カミキド
println(sortedPeople[3].name)　//さとう
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。追記したのですが、上記の場合でも可能でしょうか？

Comment: はい、出来ますよ。編集の部分を見て下さい。people列を作ったら、名前で五十音順に並び変えて、ループでprintln出来ます。

Comment: 念の為に名前は全部平仮名でしょうか？平仮名・片仮名ならコード変わりますが、簡単に出来ます。しかし、漢字も入ってるのならちょっとややこしいになります。

Comment: 電話帳のようなものを作っているので読み仮名を参考にしようと思いますので、平仮名、片仮名を想定しております。
上記のコードで、
    error: cannot invoke 'sorted' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> _)'
let sortedPeople = people.sorted { (lhs, rhs) in return lhs.name < rhs.name }
このように出てしまいます。

Comment: ごめんなさい、NSStringですね。var sortedPeople = people.sorted({ ($0.name as? String) < ($1.name as? String)  })　でいけるはずです。コード追加しました。